# FileNotFoundException while reading an uploaded file

Tags: android, permissions, filereader

I'm trying to convert an IOS App to Android. I have no experience in Android so it may be a silly question. Sorry for that:)

I've uploaded some json files into the "files" folder of the emulator by device file explorer. (not into the external storage)

**But when reading them, FileNotFoundException is thrown. (Permission denied)** The code I used for reading is as below;

```
       try {
            File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/Data/Users/profile.json");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            String contents = "";
            int i;
            while((i = fileReader.read())!= -1) {
                char ch = (char)i;
                contents += ch;
            }
            return contents;
        } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I've tried to form those files programmatically in the same directory under "files" folder, as below.

```
        String string = "{}";

        File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/Data/Users");
        file.mkdirs();

        File file2 = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/Data/Users/profile.json");
        file2.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file2);
        fos.write(string.getBytes());
        fos.close();
```

This time, I managed to read them successfully by using the above code. It seems uploading files by device file explorer leads to some permission problems. I couldn't find how to modify them. How can I fix this?

Comment: When you try to access external storage only you need runtime permission of external storage https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting&ved=2ahUKEwi25u66tbHfAhXJZCsKHegxDv8QFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw31l-83LLPvPqr4fBQzmC9H, but you seem to be using internal storage (getFilesDir()), if you have still problem, give some more information with code snippet

Comment: Yes, I’m trying to access internal storage. What kind of information should I give more? I’m uploading the files by upload command in the device file explorer and I cannot access it by the code above. When I create the same file by the second code snippet above, I can access it.

Comment: While you are testing in emulator it may be created as virtual file for you so in first case it will not work, but in original device if you have file in that location you can access it. In second code snippet of yours you are creating a file programmatically so sure that file will be created in that directory that you can access in both emulator and original device.

Comment: Hmm.. I don’t have a real Android device and I have to test my code using emulators. Is there any way to fix it other than creating files programmatically?